# Refreshing the LaTeX Database

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I want to change font of my document to *Verdana*. For this I need to refresh the LaTeX database. How is this done?

- I'm using the following distribution: **Unknown**
- I'm using the engine: **Unknown**

Comment: Are you using `pdftex`, `xetex`, or `luatex`?  The last two engines will easily let you use any installed system font by means of the `fontspec` package.

Comment: Sorry for the extensive edit, but I felt the need to do it. If I changed the meaning of the question or the goal you're trying to achieve, please tell me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To refresh the file name database of the TeX distribution MiKTeX (actual version 2.9) do the following:

- Start the Settings windows of MiKTeX with the command sequence: `Windows Start` -- `all programms` -- `Maintenance (Admin)` -- `Settings (Admin)`
- Choose `General` and click on `Refresh FNDB`

The right way to refresh the FNDB can depend on the way you have installed MikTeX as user version or administrator version. More you can learn with command `texdoc miktex` in your windows command line (see for example page 22 for "Refreshing the File Name DataBase").

Alternativly you can use the command `initexmf --admin --update-fndb` in admin mode or `initexmf --update-fndb` in user mode to refresh the file name database.