# Problems installing a new font

Tags: fonts

I have tried to install a new font: the gofonts package, version 2016-11-18.

I have located the folder where my Latex fonts are located on my computer:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/
```

I have copied the latex files (.sty and .fd files) into a new folder called gofonts (`/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gofonts`)

I restarted my computer and started the program Kile. I tried to Quickbuild a PDF file and I still get the message:

```
GoMono.sty not found.
```

I used the `\usepackage{GoMono}` command in the file.
I don't know what I have done wrong.

Comment: Welcome. At this link there is a similar question but with `MikTeX`: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70327/refreshing-the-latex-database.

Comment: Apparently, you will have to refresh the database with the command: sudo mktexlsr. I don't get the error anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to update your system and fonts:

`sudo texhash`

`sudo updmap-sys`